# Google Speech-to-Text API Unauthorized error :

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

I am creating a new Speechclient from the Google Cloud Speech library with the system environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS set to the path of my Cloud Platform service account JSON file. I am getting the following error:

INFO:

```
Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.translate(HttpStorageRpc.java:229)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.get(HttpStorageRpc.java:406)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$4.call(StorageImpl.java:217)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$4.call(StorageImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:105)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.get(StorageImpl.java:213)
    at Main.listOfObjects(Main.java:47)
    at Main.getListOfObjects(Main.java:63)
    at Main.runListOfAudioFiles(Main.java:68)
    at Main.main(Main.java:179)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket."
][1]
```

I have logged in to my GCP project in the command line with gcloud init. That did not have any effect, I am still getting the same above error.

I attempted to authorize the project with explicit credentials as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) but I got the following error:

INFO:

```
Failed to detect whether we are running on Google Compute Engine.
Failed to create the client due to: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

I am running on IntelliJ Idea with the Cloud Code plugin.

I am not sure how to proceed from here, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code that you execute?

Comment: public static ArrayList<String> listOfObjects(String str, String name) { //calls to cloud storage
        Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(str).build().getService();
        Bucket bucket = storage.get(name);
        Page<Blob> blobs = bucket.list();
        ArrayList<String> af = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Blob b: blobs.iterateAll()) {
            af.add(b.getName());
        }
        return audioFiles;
    }
    public static void Recognize(String uri) { //instanitates speech client
        try (SpeechClient sc = SpeechClient.create()) {...}}

Comment: On which OS are you running the code?